# Is there a way to allocate CPUs for my Python/multiprocessing script?

Tags: python

I understand that you can count number of logical or physical cores on a given system

```
#logical
multiprocessing.cpu_count()

#physical
import hwloc
print  hwloc.Topology().get_nbobjs_by_type(hwloc.OBJ_CORE)
```

specify pool size

```
pool = Pool(processes=4)
```

But in prod some processes are getting preempted when server is busy.

Is there a way to request a guaranteed pool size and if CPU allocation is impossible - just exit with error?

Why I want to do it: I've noticed that if I wait just for 5 seconds I often can get 3x performance improvement. So I want to loop trying to get CPU allocation I need.

Comment: Do you mean a way to do that directly from the Python API, or are you willing to muck around a bit with OS-level tooling?

Comment: You don't want to do this, but you can set process priority.

Comment: ...frankly, though, you're probably better off setting a very low niceness value than *really* dedicating CPUs. The OS scheduler will try to keep processes on the same CPU to avoid losing cache when possible. Per-process CPU pinning is possible, but you don't want to do it.

Comment: See `os.nice()` -- though with a caveat that unless you're a privileged process, you can't lower your own niceness, so you'll want whatever starts your daemon/service to be responsible for doing that setup. Since you haven't specified your OS at all, much less your process supervision system, we're not really in a position to help further with that here.